# Reference generic parameter in C# xml documentation comment

Tags: c#, .net, generics, comments, xml-documentation

How do I correctly reference the overloaded method with generic parameter in c# documentation comment? What should I put into `cref` attribute? I want Visual Studio 2010 (and ReSharper) to resolve it correctly.

```
/// <summary>
/// <see cref="MethodName(IEnumerable<string>)"/>
/// </summary>
public class ClassName
{

    public void MethodName(IEnumerable<string> param)
    {
        // code 
    }

    public void MethodName(string param)
    {
        // code 
    }
}
```

I did not find answer in this article (even though i could have missed it).
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsbx0t7x.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CodingK0ala's link I finally were able to resolve it, even though I looked in the article before and did not find the answer then.

`<see cref="MethodName(IEnumerable{string})"/>`

Thanks.

EDIT: Actually I don't know what seemed so incomprehensible about it then. :)